# NoSQL abstraction layer for Python

Tags: python, mongodb, redis, nosql

Does anybody know of an abstraction layer for nosql databases for Python similar to [SQL Alchemy](http://sqlalchemy.org) for SQL?  This would allow [redis](http://redis.io), [mongodb](http://mongodb.com), etc... to be pluggable backends without having to write for each one specifically.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Which Python API should be used with Mongo DB and Django](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2740837/which-python-api-should-be-used-with-mongo-db-and-django)

Comment: I don't know if what you're asking for exists, but bear in mind that MongoDB and Redis have some very different features. I'm not sure how well an abstraction layer for those would work.

Comment: I understand that the different features would either be disabled or abstracted - it's a tradeoff for the portability gained.

Answer (score 9):

> This would allow redis, mongodb, etc... to be pluggable backends without having to write for each one specifically.

There is django-nonrel, but that library seems to be converting SQL actions into the various library actions.

The major problem here is that these things are not really the same at all. In particular, the family grouping of "NoSQL" is a high level of abstraction.

There are graph databases and key-value databases and document databases and more. Unlike SQL, they diverge pretty quickly in terms of available features.

Answer (score 2):

You can take a look at http://www.allbuttonspressed.com/projects/django-nonrel which provides a nosql abstraction layer for Django