# Django and mongodb-engine: How do models work?

Tags: python, django, mongodb, models

I'm trying to follow this tutorial: http://django-mongodb-engine.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorial.html
But I'm getting an error when I try to import a class:

```
>>> from testApp.models import Request
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name Request
```

models.py:

```
from django.db.models import CharField
from django.db.models import Model
from django.db import models


class Request(models.Model):
    reqID = IntegerField("Request ID", primary_key = True)
       .....
```

and my settings.py:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django_mongodb_engine',
        'NAME': 'test_db',
        'USER': '',
        'PASSWORD': '',
        'HOST': '', 
        'PORT': '', 
    }
}
```

I included my testApp in INSTALLED_APPS. I just don't understand how to add data to my mongo db and make it relate to my models. Do I still run 'python manage.py sql testApp' and 'python manage.py sql syncdb'? Or do these do nothing since I'm using mongodb-engine? Any guidance would be greatly appreciated as this is my first time using python, django, or mongodb and I've spent 3 days straight following tutorials =(

Comment: thanks! I think you're right that they don't do anything. Just to clarify, I'm using mongodb-engine, not mongoengine (apparently they are completely different). I'm just trying to figure out how the models.py works in correlation with mongodb-engine.

Comment: Found this related question, but I'm with this guy. Where is the simple mongo-django guide that tells you, you don't need models? But you do? I don't get it...
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11333938/how-do-i-configure-mongodb-indexes-in-django-nonrel-without-using-models

Comment: You just use the models as normal Django models.  Eg: Request(id=1).save(), Request.objects.find() etc..